# overflow break inline display

Tags: html, css

So I have this strange problem, I have two div on one line (`display:inline-block`) and the first div appears on hover in a sliding effect. For this animation I need to set `overflow:hidden`, but it seems to break the my page.

I made a demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8nat/2/)

Have you ever face this problem ?

Thank you

NOTE: IE8+ compatible hints or solutions would be a huge plus

---

## Code

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hello NoOverflow">Hello</div><div class="textWrapper">mytext</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hello">Hello</div><div class="textWrapper">mytext</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

.hello {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    background: #F00;
}

.textWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #090;
}

.NoOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

## EDIT

For those who want the hover animation : [JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/E8nat/5/)

You will see my problem by hovering the 2nd container (the JQuery "animate" call add a "overflow: hidden" property)

Comment: I don't see any hover effect.

Comment: that was for the context, I don't need the hover effect to reproduce the problem

Comment: Made an edit to show you with the hover effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `vertical-align: top` for your inline-block child elements.

When you specify `overflow: hidden`, you are triggering a new block formatting context, and its bottom edge will align with the baseline of the following inline element.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7SZkN/

The relevant CSS to modify is:

```
.NoOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

There is pretty much CSS2 so it should work fine in IE8+ (any browser that supports inline blocks).

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. Here the demo with hover effect I was talking about : http://jsfiddle.net/E8nat/8/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to float them left.

```
.container {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

.hello {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float:left;
    width: 40px;
    background: #F00;
}

.textWrapper {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float:left;
    background: #090;
}

.NoOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```